# 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' for HTMLWorker parser

Tags: c#, itext

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 10, 10);
StringReader reader = new StringReader(edittedHTML);
HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
string fileName = "test.pdf";
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
worker.Parse(reader);
worker.EndDocument();
worker.Close();
document.Close();
```

When the program runs to worker.Parse, it throws out an error just like the title said.

The edtted HTML is the HTML string of an HTML page.

Anyone know how to solve this, or what is going wrong?

The stack trace:

```
at iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.StartElement(String tag, IDictionary`2 attrs)
at iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.ProcessTag(Boolean start)
at iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.Go(TextReader reader)
at iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.Parse(ISimpleXMLDocHandler doc, ISimpleXMLDocHandlerComment comment, TextReader r, Boolean html)
at iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.Parse(TextReader reader)
at TestPdfApplication.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\TLiu\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestPdfApplication\TestPdfApplication\Form1.cs:line 68
```

Comment: Debug and see if your worker object is actually instantiated.

Comment: @neo Yes, i think it's instantiated.

Comment: That's coming from within iTextSharp.  It looks like your HTML is broken.

Comment: @SLaks it works fine when i open same HTML in the Chrome.

Comment: It's probably broken in a way that Chrome knows how to handle, but that iTextSharp doesn't. Show us the HTML.  Running it through HTMLAgilityPack may help.

Comment: @SLaks how can i run it through HTMLAgilityPack myself?

Comment: By necessity (unfortunately) browsers have to cope with all sorts of broken html. A lot of tools that process (X)HTML are not always so lenient. There are tools if I'm not mistaken that will "fix" this (X)HTML by applying some of the same rules that browsers use and adding or modifying the HTML to be "correct" according to how a browser would interpret it, but I'm unable to come up with specific names of those tools.

Comment: I doubt anyone can give `detailed canonical answer` without a sample page/HTML file.  A wide variety of things could be wrong in the HTML.  For instance, trying to run *this* page thru the code given, I get *an* error but not the same error.

Comment: *The question is widely applicable to a large audience* - the `HTMLWorker` this questions focuses on has been deprecated a long time ago due to numerous issues. Thus, that *large audience* had better switch to using the replacement class `XmlWorker`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is a null reference exception being thrown due to `HTML tags` that the parser was unable to handle. try to remove the tags
although HTMLWorker is no longer supported.
 [It's discontinued in favor of XML Worker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a null reference. Try to use the sintaxis "using" with all the IDisposable items:

```
using (HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document))
                { (......) }
```

Comment: its not IDisposable